# Powershell script to take and delete snapshots

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, scripting

Im new to powershell and i want to create a script to take a snapshot of all the running vm's and delete the snapshots that have more than lest say 5 days. What i have is this:

```
$Time = 5 
$VMs = Get-VM | Where-Object {$._State –eq 'Running'}
foreach($VM in $VMs){
$Snapshots = Get-VMSnapshot $VM

foreach($Snapshot in $Snapshots){

    if ($snapshot.CreationTime.AddDays($Time)) {
        Remove-VMSnapshot $Snapshot

    } 
}

Checkpoint-VM $VM
}
```

But is not workin.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "But is not workin"? Where does your script seem to stop working

Comment: `if ($snapshot.CreationTime.AddDays($Time) -le (Get-Date)) {` you need to use _conditional expression_ in `if`. Although `$snapshot.CreationTime.AddDays($Time)` is not boolean value, `if` command would evaluate it to true…

Comment: And typo in `Where-Object {$._State –eq 'Running'}` should be `$_.State` instead of `$._State`. Please follow @MartynC and [edit] your question. It's a bit unclear as currently written.

Comment: Well spotted @JosefZ, I hadn't even looked at the script yet 

Comment: @JosefZ i fix the typos and add (get-date) in the last if and now is working like a charm. i will post the script with the fixes. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading some comments I was able to solve the issue I was having.The script will look like this:

```
$Days = 4 

$VMs = Get-VM | Where-Object {$_.State –eq 'Running'}
foreach($VM in $VMs){
$Snapshots = Get-VMSnapshot $VM

foreach($Snapshot in $Snapshots){

    if ($snapshot.CreationTime.AddDays($Days) -lt (get-date)) {
        Remove-VMSnapshot $Snapshot

    } 
}

Checkpoint-VM $VM
}
```

Notice that i fix the typo and also add the (get-date) part so I can compare the time with my variable.